# Why do .txt/.log/.html/.xml files have a different size after being committed?

Tags: windows, git

I am in the process of committing an existing folder, and to make sure it was committed correctly I cloned it somewhere else and compared the original and the cloned one.

For some reason it seems that a lot of non-binary files are smaller in the cloned folder than in the original folder:

```
Name                                             Length SideIndicator
----                                             ------ -------------
Readme.html                                      153226 =>
becauseofreasons.txt                                  2 =>
becauseofreasons.txt                                  2 =>
ColorTones.h                                       4037 =>
README.TXT                                         2604 =>
ReSaver.0.log.xml                                 35177 =>
LICENSE                                            1080 =>
Readme.html                                      148132 <=
becauseofreasons.txt                                  1 <=
becauseofreasons.txt                                  1 <=
ColorTones.h                                       3941 <=
README.TXT                                         2547 <=
ReSaver.0.log.xml                                 34029 <=
LICENSE                                            1060 <=
```

It's not a big difference, and casual observation seems to show the content is the same. There are no UTF-16 files in the folder, so as far as I can tell this shouldn't be an encoding issue

Comment: Do a binary diff to be sure about the content. How are you getting the size ? Is it the same file system ?

Comment: out of the blind : some issue with line endings ? `cr lf` on one side and `lf` on the other ?

Comment: @LeGEC Indeed, I got the CRLF warning on those files, that's probably it :) Feel free to submit it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it happens on text files could be linked to a `cr lf` issue : if line endings are `cr lf` in one copy of the file and `lf` in the other, the first copy will be bigger, in size.

Check the config parameters regarding line endings in both your clones.